# Manual approximation of $\operatorname{sech}(0.7)$

Tags: approximation, hyperbolic-functions

In the archive of a midterm exam collection there are some question like the one above.

> How can we approximate expressions like
>   $$\operatorname{sech}(0.7)$$
>   without a calculator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they not say how close the approximation should be?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$cosh (x) = (e^x+e^{-x})/2 = 1+x^2/2 +x^4/24+..$$

Thus $$cosh (.7) \approx 1+(.7)^2/2+(.7)^4/24 =1.255$$

Therefore $$sech (0.7) \approx 0.7968$$

Comment: @Travis  Thanks for your attention and comment. I fixed my typo.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\log 2 = 0.693\ldots \approx \frac{7}{10}$---this is certainly worth memorizing if you haven't---then you can deduce
$$\operatorname{sech} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right) \approx \operatorname{sech} \log 2 = \frac{2}{\exp(\log 2) + \exp(-\log 2)} = \frac{2}{2 + \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{4}{5} ,$$
which has a relative error of $< 0.3\%$.

Comment: That's just what I was thinking, too; but I wanted the OP to tell us what would be counted as accurate enough; also, whether by any chance the fact that $2 \bumpeq e^{0.7}$ had come up somewhere earlier in the course ...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I prefaced the answer with "If you know that...". I expect a typical student, though, has seen a numerical value for $\log 2$ at least once before seeing $\operatorname{sech}$.